# Limit of $(\int\limits_0^n (1+\arctan^2x )\,dx )^ {\frac{1}{n}}$

Tags: integration, limits

I need to find out this limit. Could someone help me?
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \Big(\int\limits_0^n (1+\arctan^2x )\,dx \Big)^ {\frac{1}{n}}$$ = ?

I have tried taking logarithm then calculating the integral of $arctan^{2}(x)$, it got worse, it seems to me that there is some shorter solution..

Comment: What about your thoughts on the problem? Did you try to take logarithm of both sides, and use l'Hopital rule? Please include it in your question

Comment: Do you know the limit of $n^{1/n}$ as $n\to+\infty$?

Comment: @Jakobian, have tried taking logarithm then calculating the integral of $arctan^{2}(x)$, it got worse, it seems to me that there is some shorter solution..

Comment: @Emathke I actually said "Please include it in your question" to avoid you writing it to me in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your integrand is bounded as
$$
1\leq 1+\arctan^2x\leq 1+\frac{\pi^2}{4}.
$$
Thus, your integral is between $n$ and $n(1+\pi^2/4)$. Taking the $n$th root and using the squeeze theorem for limits together with the facts that
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}n^{1/n}=1
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
\lim_{n\to+\infty}a^{1/n}=1
$$
should get you to the goal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: After taking the logarithm, try using l'hopital.